# Intercepting input from the OS

Tags: c, operating-system, keylogger

I would like to learn with an example before next semester and want to try something which works together with the OS.

How can a C program intercept input from the OS. The only example I can think of is a Keylogger.

How can a C program be programmed to dig into the Operation System?

Does this make sense?

Comment: This is platform specific. Which OS?

Comment: Did you choose an operating system you would like to focus on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you could watch the device nodes for all keyboards and record the received events.

The `/dev/input/event*` nodes provide a generic interface - you would have to watch any of them that correspond to a mouse or keyboard. You need the `evdev` kernel module for this to be available.

The [`/usr/include/linux/input.h`](http://debomatic.debian.net/natty/natty/usr/include/linux/input.h) header file contains most of what you'd need to know about the programming interface. From my experience, it's quite straightforward and simple to use.

Keep in mind that some X-server drivers will grab their device node and block all other applications from getting events, so you may have to either change their options or use an X-based interface as well.

I think that this is about as far as you can get on Linux without writing a kernel module.

EDIT:

You should realise that each OS has its own interface for the input subsystem. There is no cross-platform way to do this. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Basically depending on OS you need to "hook" into the event mechanism of the OS. There are different events happening in an OS and a key press is an event just like a mouse click. It is possible to hook into these events and provide a function that the OS calls whenever the event happens.

E.g. [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows